# Custom extension in rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to serve rails generated zip files.
For example from the following REST route:
http://foo.com/controller/show/filename.zip

How i need to map routes.rb to allow the routing of zip files (instead searching for static files in /public) to my controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've set up your routes using the `map.resources` in `config/routes.rb` then I think you already have the routes you want. What I think you need is to add a custom mime type to you controller like this:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "application/zip", :zip
```

Then

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.zip { ... }
end
```

Also available in `request.format`

Comment: I get a 404. I setup a map.resources :controller in routes.rb

Comment: How i do the same for tar.gz files?

Comment: I believe the MIME type you're looking for ".tar.gz" is "application/x-gzip" so just register another alias for that and you're good to go. Did you resolve your 404? If you run `rake routes` do you see the resource's paths and format rules?

Comment: if i use tar.gz i get a 404, for zip works. seems that the point between tar.gz it's the issue

Comment: yes, for sure the problem is in routes.rb that don't route .tar.gz

Comment: Perhaps try an explicit routing specification like this: `map.connect('files/*path.:format', :controller => 'my_controller', 
        :action => 'my_action', :requirements => {:format => /(zip|tar.gz)/})`, obviously with your controller and action substituted